# alternatives of sharpe's ratio with respect to maximum-drawdown(mdd)

Tags: sharpe-ratio, maximum-drawdown

Given a window, expected return divided by standard deviation is sharpe's ratio.

But I want to form another figure for mdd-adjusted return.

mdd divided by expected return can be suggested but it seems inappropriate.

How can I make such a formula?

Comment: What's wrong with return/mdd?

Comment: return / mdd is called the Calmar ratio. Although the Calmar ratio is widely applied in the industry, one possible reason why it seems problematic at least theoretically is that while there is a simple and explicit way to scale return (the numerator) w.r.t. time under certain assumptions, e.g. expected annualised return = 12 * expected monthly return, there aren't such simple relationships for mdd (the denominator) ,e.g. you can't "annualise" a mdd. Therefore the length of window over which return / mdd is calculated becomes a concern.

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider shortfall metrics such as VaR and CVaR which scale much more elegantly w.r.t. time than mdd, in which case your metric becomes something like return / VaR or return / CVaR.